# How to stop jumping to the top of a page in a setIntervall() function? (return false or preventDefault?)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

In my rails app I want to call a controller#action with ajax every 10 seconds. This is working perfectly fine. However, everytime my code is executed, the page jumps back to the top, which I do not want.

**This is my code so far:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  setInterval(function(){
    $.ajax({
            url: "/posts/update_counter", // Route to the controller#action
            type: "POST",
    });
    return false;
  }, 10 * 1000);

});
```

Searching for similar problems yielded solutions with `return false` and/or `preventDefault()`, however I cannot make it work in a `setIntervall()`.

**My posts_controller.rb**

```
#Everytime this action is called, some columns should be updated (namely: lowviews, highviews, lowlikes, highlikes)

def update_counter
  @fposts = Fpost.all

  @fposts.each do |fp|
    fp.update_attributes(lowviews: fp.lowviews + rand(5..10), 
                         highviews: fp.highviews + rand(5..10),
                         lowlikes: fp.lowlikes + rand(1..5),
                         highlikes: fp.highlikes + rand(1..5))
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to posts_path }
    format.js 
  end
end
```

**In my routes.rb**

```
post 'posts/update_counter' => 'posts#update_counter'
```

Comment: The code in the question *doesn't* cause a jump to the top of the page. You've accidentally left that part out. Proof: https://jsfiddle.net/a0fqheyp/

Comment: I've updated my question with my relevant ruby files :).

Comment: The Ruby files are completely irrelevant. It doesn't matter what the controller returns in response to the ajax request. Unless something in your JavaScript code is doing something with that response which causes the scrolling (which isn't in the JavaScript code you've quoted), nothing it returns can cause that.

Comment: I don't know RoR, but it looks like there's some JS in your response. `format.js` Guessing the problem is there?

Comment: @T.J. Crowder: Mhh that is really strange, because this is the only JS code I've written so far. The thing is: Ajax calls the controller#action in my rails controller, this controller#action updates the database and without reloading the page, my html views are updated every 10 seconds as well. Although I did not specify anything in the `success: `-part of the ajax-call.